# REST API which needs multiple different resources?

Tags: json, api, rest, http

I'm designing a REST api for running jobs on virtual machines in different domains (Active Directory domains, the virtual machines with the same name can exist in different domains).

```
/domains
/domains/{dname}
/domains/{dname}/vms
/domains/{dname}/vms/{cname}
```

And for jobs, which will be stored in a database

```
/jobs
/jobs/{id}
```

Now I need to add a new API for the following user stories.

1. As a user, I want to run a job (just job definition, not the stored job) on an existing VM.
2. As a user, I want to run a job (just job definition, not the stored job) on VM named `x`, which may or may not exist. The system should create the VM if `x` doesn't exist.

How should the api be designed?

**Approach 1:**

```
PUT /domains/{dname} 
{ "state": "running_job", "vm": "vm_name", "job_definition": { .... } }
```

**Approach 2:**

```
PUT /domains/{dname}/vms/{vm_name}
{ "state": "running_job", "job_definition": { .... } }
```

**Approach 3:**

```
PUT /jobs
{ "state": "running", "domain": "name", "vm": "vm_name", "job_definition": { .... } }
```

**Approach 4:** create a new resource, saying scheduler,

```
PUT /scheduler
{ "domain": "name", "vm": "vm_name", "job_definition": { .... } }
```

(what if I need to update some attributes of scheduler in the future?)

In general, hwo to design the REST API url which needs multiple resources?

Comment: `/jobs` does not fit, because it's for stored jobs. You did not tell what `/domains` actually do. Maybe fits, maybe not

Comment: Updated the question - `"domain": "name"` is added to approach 3 and 4. Domain is Active Directory domain.

Answer (score 1):

> How should the api be designed?

How would you design this on the web?

There would be an HTML form, right?  With a bunch of input controls to collect information from the operator about what job to use, and which VM to target, and so on.  Operator would fill in the details, submit the form.  The browser would then use the form to create the appropriate HTTP request to send to the server (the request-target being computed from the form meta data).

Since the server gets to decide what the request-target should be (benefits of using [hypertext](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)), it can choose any resource identifier it wants.  In HTTP, a successful unsafe request happens to invalidate previously cached responses with the same request target, so one possible strategy is to consider which is the most important resource changed by successfully handling the request, and use that resource as the target.

In this specific case, we might have a resource that represents the job queue (ex /jobs), and what we are doing here is submitting a new entry in the queue, so we might expect

```
POST /jobs HTTP/1.1
....
```

If the server, in its handling of the request, also creating new resources for the specific job, then those would be indicated in the response

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /jobs/931a8a02-1a87-485a-ba5b-dd6ee716c0ef
....
```

---

Could you instead just use PUT?

```
PUT  /jobs/931a8a02-1a87-485a-ba5b-dd6ee716c0ef HTTP/1.1

???
```

Yes, if (a) the client knows what spelling to use for the request-target and (b) is the client knows what the representation of the resource should look like.

Which unsafe HTTP method you use in the messages that trigger you business activities doesn't actually matter very much.  You need to use the methods correctly (so that general purpose HTTP connectors don't get misled).

In particular, the important thing to remember about PUT is that the request body should be a complete representation of the resource - in other words, the request body for a PUT should match the response body of a GET.  Think "save file"; we've made local edits to our copy of a resource, and we send back a copy of the entire document.

Comment: I think I should use PATCH in all the example.